# jqueryui draggable/sortable not working when the sortable changes size?

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an item being dragged into a sortable. The sortable's size is dynamic, and grows when dragging starts. The sortable's new larger area doesn't seem to count as a valid dropzone the way I'd expect, and only the initial area is valid for dropping.

Is there a way to tell the draggable/sortable to "update"?

Essentially, something like this:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    start: function () {
        $('.sortable').width(300);
    }
});
```

I have a jsfiddle demonstrating this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/o4oLcu0g/

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I updated your fiddle with an answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/o4oLcu0g/1/

I made one minor change:

```
.group {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

`sortable` is trying to add the object to the right or left of the current elements as well as above and below. Setting the `max-width` will prvent the growth.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The growth is desirable. What I want is for the full 300px width to be a valid dropzone for the draggable.

Comment: Ok, I see. I did misunderstand. So you want to add it to a 2nd column of DIVs? So that it is to the right of the first column? I would think that would be something you'd do in the `drop` of draggable, and not so much in sortable.

Comment: @user3190946 When I test it in FireFox, the entire area is droppable.

Comment: @user3190946 I have been working on this and I think it's a `tolerance` issue. When the div is expanded, the sortable items are still only 50px wide. It needs to sort object to object based on it's intersection. I think this will help explain the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/efettbdp/

Comment: One thing to note is that this only happens on the first run. nth attempts after work as desired.

Comment: All I want is for jqueryui to recognize that the element is 300px wide and not 100px.

Comment: @user3190946 it recognizes that `.group` is 300px wide, but it's sorting the `.item` and those are only 50px wide. Since the `tolorance` default is `intersect`(http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-tolerance), the item you drag in has to intersect with the items it's being sorted with. This is why you cannot drag the item to any part of the `.group` and get it to sort on the first run.

Comment: If the `.group` element starts out 300px wide, the entire area is droppable. http://jsfiddle.net/Lukea4wu/

Comment: @user3190946 .group is `100px` large when the page loads. When the `drag` event starts, .group is then changed to `300px` large. The whole area is not droppable, it is sortable. Meaning the `div` can be sorted in with the other sortable `div` items. If you want to make `.group` droppable, you will need to make use of `.droppable()`.